# Users loop in Meteor Js

Tags: mongodb, meteor

For example I have 50 users and I have collection like

```
Rooms = new Mongo.Collection('rooms');
```

First I want to mix Users like if I have this `[id1,id2,id3...]` make it this `[id52,id91241,id2...]`

and after  put in every `Room` 5 users like

```
for (i=0;i<countofmyusers;i=i+5)
   crete new room and put 5 users // ?? how .. Rooms.insert(??)

 { 
    users: [id1,id44,id2451,id921241,id23]
    ...
 }
```

Any idea how to do it ?

Comment: Can a user only be in one room?

Comment: no, if for example I have 51 users, than create 10 rooms

Comment: how i can try if i dont know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example function that creates a set of rooms, each with a random sample of users:

```js
var randomRooms = function(roomCount, sampleSize) {
  // extract all of the user ids in the datbase
  var userIds = _.pluck(Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {_id: 1}}).fetch(), '_id');

  // create roomCount rooms
  _.times(roomCount, function() {
    // insert a new room with a random sample of users of size sampleSize
    Rooms.insert({users: _.sample(userIds, sampleSize)});
  });
};
```

---

Here's a new version which enforces that user ids not be repeated across groups (i.e. each user will be assigned to one and only one group):

```js
var randomRooms = function(userCountInEachRoom) {
  // extract all of the user ids in the datbase
  var userIds = _.pluck(Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {_id: 1}}).fetch(), '_id');

  // create a new array of randomly sorted user ids
  var shuffledUserIds = _.shuffle(userIds);

  // create a list of lists of user ids where each list has at most
  // userCountInEachRoom ids - note that users will not be repeated in any lists
  var userLists = [];
  while (shuffledUserIds.length > 0)
    userLists.push(shuffledUserIds.splice(0, userCountInEachRoom));

  // insert a new group for each sub-array of user ids
  _.each(userLists, function(users) {
    Rooms.insert({users: users});
  });
};
```

You'd call it like `randomRooms(5)` to place at most five users in each group. Note that the last group will have fewer than five users if the total user count is not a multiple of five.

Comment: `sampleSize` - what is it ? It is count of users that I put in 1 room ? And  `_,sample` produce a random sample from the userIds, 
it turns out that people can be repeated in different rooms or the user can not be in several rooms at once like `room1{ users: [id1..]} , room2 {users : [id1..} ` - it should not be

Comment: yep, it repeat users, so people from room 2 can be in room1 and in room3  and etc., but how put 5 users in one room and not to find this users in other rooms

Comment: I updated the answer with a new version which ensures each user will only belong to one new group.